# simple function statement is not giving any output

Tags: python-3.x

Tried to write a simple function in python version 3.7 system is neither giving any error nor it is giving any output.

```
def say_hello():
  print('Hello user')

  say_hello()
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Do *not* post images of code or links to images of code. Always post code in the question itself as formatted text. Then if you deem it helpful, feel free to provide a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation for a code block (body of a function, loop etc.) i.e it starts with indentation and ends with the first unindented line.
So your method invocation was inside the method definition because of that it didn't even printed any output below code will fix your problem.

```
def say_hello():
  print('Hello User')

say_hello()
```